# convert number from base n to an integer

Tags: c, radix

So I'm hoping to get a little guidance on this one. I have a function that takes a radix(base) and then using getchar() will get the number to convert from the given radix to an integer representation.

The only argument given is the radix number, then getchar() gets the number representation via the command line.

So if I pass

```
str2int 16
input a number: 3c
```

It should output (16^1*3) + (16^0*12) = 48 + 12 = **60**.

I fully understand the math, and different ways of converting bases, but don't know how to go about coding something up. The math is always MUCH easier than the code, at least to me.

Another way to compute would be:
(702) base 15 = 15*7 + 0 = 105; 15*105 + 2 = **1577**

I don't know how to express this in C only using getchar()? Is it possible to do without using the math function?

Comment: Why `getchar()`? You can just read the string in and use `strtol`. If you must use `getchar()`, then just read each number in and `output = output * base + current_digit`

Comment: Your conversion of `702 (base15)` to `(base 10)` is not even close to correct. It is `7*15^2 + 0*15^1 + 2*15^0`, or `1577 (base 10)`

Comment: @WhozCraig That's a little harsh; only one of the poster's terms is actually wrong.

Comment: You tagged the question [c], then you mentioned the `math class`.  C does not have classes, those two concepts are incompatible.

Comment: @ WhozCraig – my bad, I multiplied the second portion, 105, by 7 instead of 15. Corrected now.

Comment: No worries. Nicely done. So do you have a plan for how base numbers beyond 16 are to be input (or is there a ceiling that you only need to handle up to base-16 ?

Comment: Use `long int strtol (const char* str, char** endptr, int base);`.  It's all there.

Comment: @abelenky – sorry, new to C – used to working in PHP, Java, JavaScript.

Comment: @ WhozCraig – only working up to base 16.

Comment: Then @chux is totally correct. [`strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) will handle everything up to base-36 without a hitch (at least as far as I remember).

Comment: @chux – thanks, trying to do it without the use of strings or arrays. Attempting to do this in the most primitive way possible :)

Comment: @shparkison: The command line argument that you specify for your base is already a string. Anyway, how would you do it without strings or arrays in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep getting one `char` at a time until not a digit or no more are needed.

```
unsigned shparkison(unsigned base) {
  unsigned sum = 0;
  int ch;
  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    // one could instead look up the toupper(value) in an array "0123...ABC...Z"; 
    // Following assumes ASCII
    if (isdigit(ch)) ch -= '0';
    else if (islower(ch)) ch -= 'A' - 10;
    else if (isupper(ch)) ch -= 'a' - 10;
    else {
      break; // Not a digit
    }
    if (ch >= base) {
      break; // Digit too high
    }
    unsigned sum_old = sum;
    sum *= base;
    sum += ch;
    if (sum < sum_old) {
      sum = sum_old;
      break; // Overflow
    }
  }
  ungetc(ch, stdin);
  return sum;
}
```